# Java - Won't read out File content

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a .txt file with, for example, this content:

```
variable1="hello";
variable2="bye";
testing3="parameter";
whatisthis4="hello";
var5="exampletext";
example=3;
wellthen=8;
---
```

It read in the file, line by line, fine until I added a way of saving the data.

This whole code plus another reader (with other variable names of course) is wrapped in a try-catch statement.

```
String path_playlist = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
String fileName_playlist = path_playlist 
        + "/src/dancefusion/game/playlist.txt";
FileReader fr_playlist = new FileReader(fileName_playlist);
BufferedReader br_playlist = new BufferedReader(fr_playlist);

int track_counter = track_sum*9;
String trackinfos[] = new String[track_counter];

while(track_counter < 0)
{
    System.out.println("linecount="+track_counter);
    trackinfos[track_counter] = br_playlist.readLine();
    System.out.println(trackinfos[track_counter]);
    track_counter--;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(trackinfos));
```

In this example track_sum equals 1.

The while loop should read in the file one line at a time but only reads null's:

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

---

**Update 1:**

The while-condition was set up the wrong way... thanks!

The corrected version:

```
while(track_counter < 0)
```

However, now it gives me an exception with an "ArrayOutOfBounds: 9".

Any guesses?

---

**Final Update:**

As mentioned by @GiorgiMoniava, I just needed to reduce track_counter by one before starting to read in as in Java arrays begin with 0, thanks!

```
int track_counter = track_sum*8;
String trackinfos[] = new String[track_counter];

track_counter--;

while(track_counter >= 0)
{
    System.out.println("linecount="+track_counter);
    trackinfos[track_counter] = br_playlist.readLine();
    System.out.println(trackinfos[track_counter]);
    track_counter--;
}
```

---

Maybe one of you can figure out what I did wrong...

Of course I can deliver more information/code if needed!
**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: maybe a typo? while(track_counter > 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks weird

```
while(track_counter < 0)
```

Are you sure loop is ever entered in? It is my guess (from your output) that `track_counter` is 9.

About your array out of bounds exception: if you create array of size N you can only access it using indexes: [0, N-1]

Comment: it doesnt make sense since he is also referencing an array index with this track_counter which, if entered, will be < 0. but i dont think it enters that part

Comment: @Apostolos I also don't think loop is entered in; ps. not a Java expert, just a guess

Comment: Thanks, this solved the first part - now it seems that it enters the loop - however I am getting a 

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9

Any idea how to get rid of that too?
Thanks!

Comment: @yes, check update. You can't access at index track_counter until decrement

Comment: trackcounter is 9 but your array is 0 to 8.

Comment: @KaiAdam Doesn't matter point is if you have array with size 500 you can only access elements at index 0, ..., 499

Comment: @KaiAdam Because you probably are still trying to access last element via `[500]` which is out of bounds (which are `0-499` for that case). Problem is not in array size, but in way you are trying to access its elements.

Comment: Thanks! I just solved it - I updated my main post :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   while(track_counter > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("linecount="+track_counter);
        track_counter--;
        trackinfos[track_counter] = br_playlist.readLine();
        System.out.println(trackinfos[track_counter]);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out - however, @GiorigeMoniava got it first :S

Comment: ok this doenst stop you from upvoting the answer for being helpful. you can accept giorrgi's answer of course :)

Comment: I upvoted both answers of course :)
Sadly it says that my votes won't be visible as I am still below 15 reputation points :S